# С# EmguCV ошибка "OpenCV: type == CV_32F || type == CV_64F"

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

Нужен метод, который будет инвертировать видео.
В метод передается текущий кадр. Для работы с CvInvoke.Invert нужна глубина картинки float или double, что я и делаю первой строчкой

```
Image<Bgr, double> input = frame.ToImage<Bgr,double>();
```

Далее пытаюсь сделать инверсию через уже готовый метод

```
CvInvoke.Invert(input, input, DecompMethod.Normal);
```

Но он все равно выдает ошибку "OpenCV: type == CV_32F || type == CV_64F", хотя тип матрицы Cv64F
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Странно, но инверсия заработала с вызовом `CvInvoke.BitwiseNot(frame, frame);`, но вопрос все равно остается актуальным